# Using PKCE authentication in Sitecore 9.2 with .Net framework

Tags: authentication, .net

We are using `Sitecore 9.2` (Identity Server 4). Which is currently not using `PKCE authorization`(Proof Key for Code Exchange). Our current site is on the .Net framework and I would like to know whether such Sitecore software configuration can support the `PKCE` approach or not.

Comment: Did you check this? https://devforum.okta.com/t/authentication-ticket-value-null-in-authorization-code-received-event/11098

Comment: I think they are using something like this with Sitecore